# Can't compile sourcers - no such file or directory <libpq-fe.h>

Tags: postgresql, qt, compiler-errors, compilation, pgmodeler

I tried to compile sources of pgmodeler 0.7.2 (https://github.com/pgmodeler/pgmodeler/releases) but I have problem:

```
C:\Users\Krzysztof\Desktop\pgmodeler-0.7.2\libpgconnector\src\resultset.cpp:19: In file included from ..\..\pgmodeler-0.7.2\libpgconnector\src\resultset.cpp:19:0:
C:\Users\Krzysztof\Desktop\pgmodeler-0.7.2\libpgconnector\src\resultset.h:32: error: libpq-fe.h: No such file or directory
 #include <libpq-fe.h>
                      ^
In file included from ..\..\pgmodeler-0.7.2\libpgconnector\src\resultset.cpp:19:0:
..\..\pgmodeler-0.7.2\libpgconnector\src\resultset.h:32:22: fatal error: libpq-fe.h: No such file or directory
 #include <libpq-fe.h>
                      ^
compilation terminated.
```

My XML / PostgreSQL variables configuration:

```
windows {
 PGSQL_LIB = C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.3/lib/libpq.dll
 PGSQL_INC = C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.3/include
 XML_INC = C:/Qt/5.4/mingw491_32/bin/include
 XML_LIB = C:/Qt/5.4/mingw491_32/bin/include/libxml2-2.7.8.win32/bin/libxml2.dll
}
```

Comment: you might need `<libpq/libpq-fe.h>` or  `C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.3/include/libpq`  I can't test it here.

Comment: Here's a guide I wrote on how to compile pgModeler 0.9.3 on Ubuntu https://medium.com/@mglaving/how-to-compile-pgmodeler-0-9-3-on-ubuntu-20-04-19f045ec5b1d

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
PGSQL_LIB = "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.3/lib/libpq.dll"
PGSQL_INC = "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.3/include"
```

(".../Program Files/..." - has space)